# FoxySheep build error in python

Tags: python, parsing, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to build [FoxySheep](https://github.com/rljacobson/FoxySheep) for python. But I am getting the following error:

Here is the log:

```
~/Downloads/FoxySheep-master$  cd python_target
~/Downloads/FoxySheep-master/python_target$  make
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 -o generated -visitor ../FoxySheep.g4
make: antlr4: No such file or directory
make: *** [generated/FoxySheepParser.py] Error 1
```

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have antlr4 installed on your system. There is a quickstart on http://www.antlr.org that should get you up and running.